# jquery: select all elements after nth

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have x number of `<div>` and I need to select all after n.

```
<div class=foo>4:00</div>
<div class=foo>5:00</div>
<div class=foo>6:00</div>
<div class=foo>7:00</div>
<div class=foo>8:00</div>
```

For example, given n=3 and `div.foo`, remove all `div.foo` after the 3rd `div.foo` would yield:

```
<div class=foo>4:00</div>
<div class=foo>5:00</div>
<div class=foo>6:00</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Voted up. was instantly useful to me! :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$('.foo:gt(2)').remove();
```

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/MYY9m/

This uses the `greater-than` selector to select all elements who's index is greater than the number provided.

- http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Comment: That's the one I was looking for. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do:

```
$('.foo').slice(3).remove();
```

See http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: +1 This is how the jQuery docs say to do it for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Not as elegant as Patrick DW's solution, but this also works:

```
$('.foo').eq(2).nextAll().remove();
```

See http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Answer (score 0):

It is efficient to use slice  or eq since gt does not accept variables. for example

//will not work

`var items_to_remove = 8;`

`$("li:gt(items_to_remove)").remove();`

//will work

`var items_to_remove = 8;`

`$('li').slice(items_to_remove).remove();`