# Remove dynamically loaded content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to remove some div elements that are added with a wordpress loop via a get_template_part();.

The structure is something like this:

```
<div id="level1" class="col-0-1 noPad">
    get_template_part('new-story');   
</div>
```

*I've cut out most of the loop for readability.*

The template part is structured like this:

```
<div class="col-OuterContainer noPad">
  stuff
</div>
```

So in practice it looks more like this:

```
 <div id="level1" class="col-0-1 noPad">
    <div class="col-OuterContainer noPad">
      stuff
    </div>  
</div>
```

I want to detect whether there's more than 2 divz named "col-OuterContainer", then remove the divz there after. I thought it was pretty straight forward and tried this:

```
var num = $('.col-OuterContainer').length;
if (num > 2) {
   $('#level1>div:gt(1)').remove();
}
```

I currently have 3 posts at the moment so the third should have been removed, but it hasn't. I'm getting a console.log of 3 so it obviously know there are 3 elements there so why is it not removing the third element?

**Update: So I've played around some more with the code.**

The wp loop is still the same:

```
 <div id="level1" class="col-0-1 noPad">
        get_template_part('new-story');   
    </div>
```

The code inside get_template_part is this:

```
<div class="col-OuterContainer noPad"><div>stuff 1</div></div>
```

The JS is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
console.log( $('.col-OuterContainer').length );
$('#level1 .noPad:gt(1)').remove();     
});
```

I'm getting this output:

```
<div id="level1" class="col-0-1 noPad">
<div class="col-OuterContainer noPad"><div>stuff 1</div></div>
<div class="col-OuterContainer noPad"><div>stuff 1</div></div>
<div class="col-OuterContainer noPad"><div>stuff 1</div></div>
</div>
```

Console shows 3 elements but won't remove the third element even if I target noPad or .col-OuterContainer.

Comment: What is this #level1>div:gt(1), is level1 the container?

Comment: Yes it is, the container of the template part.

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/K5Q3B/

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact I'm using the wordpress function get_template_part() but event then I wouldn't be getting a console.log of 3 if that were the case. I'm not sure why it's not working :/

Comment: Well, @IrvinDomininakaEdward beat me by a couple of minutes, but I created a *very* similar jsFiddle, but threw in your JS conditional for the hell of it: http://jsfiddle.net/7MRg6/ - my best suggestion would be that you maybe have an element reference conflict or some other JS somewhere that is interrupting or countermanding this routine.

Comment: @KyleJoseph `get_template_part` is preprocessed, so it's unlikely to conflict with a client-side process like Javascript. You mention it's in a loop - wouldn't it make more sense to put a count conditional inside a PHP loop, rather than get JS to do the heavy lifting?

Comment: Is this being executed on doc ready or after the AJAX fetch? if it's a one-off on doc ready, you're _never_ going to find the new content. Maybe bind to `$.ajaxComplete`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Adjusted Selector

Modify the jQuery selector to:

```
<script>
    $('#level1 .noPad:gt(1)').remove();
       //Or 
    $(document).find('#level1 .noPad:qt(1)').remove();
</script>
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/K5Q3B/6/

Adjusted this after your previous selector was failing when more `<div>`s were introduced (See [example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Q3B/4/)). Alternatively, you could try what this person suggested in another [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373681/292735):

```
<script>
   $('#level1 .noPad').slice(3).remove();
</script>
```

---

### Removing *Dynamically* loaded `<div>`'s

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
       .. //Other Opts
       success: function( data ) {
          $('#somediv').html( data );
          var NodesToRemove = $(document).find('#level1 > div:gt(1)'); 
          //Or $('#somediv').find('#level1 .noPad:qt(1)').remove(); 
          NodesToRemove.remove();
       });
    });
</script>
```

---

### Prevention in PHP:

As others in the comments mentioned, it would be much better to prevent this in PHP - then you wouldn't need to consider any JavaScript for removing any of the `<div>`s at all,

```
$Counter = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
       $Counter++;
       the_post(); 
       if ( $Counter <= 2 )
           get_template_part('new-story'); 
    } 
}
```

Furthermore you could rewrite the PHP to have an AJAX Condition,

```
$Counter = 0;
$isAjax = ( isset( $_GET["ajax"] ) && $_GET["ajax"] == 'true' ? true : false );
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
       $Counter++;
       the_post(); 
       if ( !$isAjax || ( $isAjax && $Counter <= 2 ))
           get_template_part('new-story'); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mackiee, I basically have a js function that detects a media query on window resize, I have a similar function that uses ajax to load in some html so I get your concept, completely. Adding a counter into that php would work fine and if it's my only option I'll do it but $('#level1>div:gt(1)').remove(); just seemed so much more simple. I'm just a bit confused why it didn't work, while a simple console.log .length clearly detects 3 elements.

Comment: p.s I should also clarify that on larger screen widths I'm using a wp loop to get me 4 template parts, then I use js to detect a media query, which I then, depending on what query that is, adjust the amount of template parts to get. Obviously if I want more I will need to use the ajax/html method but if I want less I was just going to use the .remove js method.

Comment: Well I hope you're able to out what it was =) Especially from one Oxford dude to another by the way! :D Good luck =]!

Comment: Ahaha, I noticed that the last time you commented. I just tried it you updated fiddle, no luck. I'll update my question with more details. Thanks man.

Comment: Added an Suggestion I found digging around SO, although were you able to find out what it was?

Comment: Sweeeet, slice worked. I actually came across slice but ended up ignoring it when I came across :gt then forgot about it :). I'm still baffled by it not working, even more so now that slice works. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: Wahey! :D I have no clue either, indeed `:qt` should of (and did in Fiddles!) anyways, but glad it worked =) np!

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = $('.col-OuterContainer').length;
```

This will give you the number of `div`s with class `col-OuterContainer` in the whole document.

```
$('#level1>div:gt(1)') { ...
```

This selector only counts `div` which are direct children of the `#level1` node.

Do you have `.col-OuterContainer` in other places on your page, or nested deeper inside your `#level1` node ?